# Prevent Javascript Caching

Tags: playframework

I frequently modify my JS files, so I'd like to be able to simply refresh the page and see the changes.

However, my Network tab shows HTTP 304 (Not Modified). I believe this means that Scala Play is caching my JavaScript file.

I added the following to conf/application.conf:

> http.cacheControl=0

But I'm still getting HTTP 304's.

Answer (score 0):

For developing time try to add random number as unused GET params for script src. This will not cause logic in any way as far as script is just resource. But this will prevent caching generally.

Comment: Does that mean add `?<random #>=<random #>` to the end of my URL? I've tried that, but there's still caching